# Set Seed in a customPDF Class Using scipy.stats

Tags: scipy, seed

I need to have a seed so my random data is consistent while testing, but the seed I set when I define my_cv is not working--the data is different each time.

```
class customPDF(st.rv_continuous):


    def _pdf(self,r):

        return r**2

    nmin = -1
    nmax = 1
    my_cv = customPDF(a=nmin, b=nmax,seed = 100)

    

def __init__(self):
    self.y = random.uniform(-1,1)
    
    self.x = my_cv.rvs(size=1)
    
    self.distances = self.distanceToCandidates([self.x,self.y],election.candidates)
    self.candidateIndexes = []
    x = 0
    for distance in self.distances:
        self.candidateIndexes.append(x)
        x +=1
```

Comment: what happens if you put `numpy.seed(0)` at the start of your test?

Comment: also, `customPDF`, as you've defined it here, doesn't accept any parameters